# Unable to Group the Date Time Intervals in Excel

Tags: excel-2016

I'm finding it difficult to group the date time column into 2 hour intervals. I have tried using pivot table to group but was unable to. I have even tried using the Trunc formula to just get the date but failed. Any help would be highly appreciated. Please find attached the exact question that I'm talking about along with the excel data sheet.

[Excel Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iAc_d3P3jVHC4L8k0TByMrcwnDdSDsxSwzX6pbSLpOk/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: This is some kind of homework or assignment, according to the text in the screenshot. Your course materials will provide the tools to solve this problem, using techniques you have covered in the course. This assignment is testing YOUR knowledge about the topic, not ours.

Comment: Well, to be honest, this was an open book project about automation of repetitive tasks. After trying to solve it, i reached out for help. Btw there was no course involved

Comment: There is no simple, one-formula approach. You will need formulas to calculate what bin each record falls into before you can perform any grouping.

Comment: I understand that there's no simple formula approach to this... could you pls suggest me how do i proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Interval column contains text. Before you can do any analysis, you need to split this column into two, start and finish and make sure that the two columns are recognized by Excel as date/time values, not text. This can be achieved with the Text To Columns command, or with Power Query (much easier).

Next, you can pull out the hour value and the date of the start date into new columns. The hour column will then contain numbers from 0 to 23. Again, this is much easier with Power Query than with formulas.

With this data, you can build a pivot table that arranges the data by date and groups in two-hour intervals.

The question that is posed in your sample file cannot be answered with the available data, because the data only shows how many calls came in at what time slot. It does not have any information about the time it took to process a call and how long the call remained in the queue. There is no data that would help analyze if an SLA of 24 hrs or 12 hrs is met.